# DataTables Colvis Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Looking how to combine datatables colvis extension and responsive. 
Search that in past versions it was impossible. Wondering if there's a progress or if somebody found a way to make them work together.
What i'm looking to do: keep responsive ability of the table (to shrink and extend on different window sizes) and to be able to select what columns will be visible. 
For now i can make desired column to be hidden, but when changing window size all columns became visible and responsive overrides the colvis settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions for implementing [Buttons extension with Column visibility](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) and [Responsive extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/).
You have to use `Buttons extension`, because [Colvis](https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/) is retired.

First solution is add both extension together, it works. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jezrael/rbvmmhvk/).
Only you need set width of table to `100%`.

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'colvis'
    ],
    responsive: true
} );
```

Next solution: [Link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29860/using-colvis-button-with-responsive-table-disables-hidden-columns)
You have to add `responsive` classes to tag `table` and in JavaScript call only `Buttons colvis` extension.

```
<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" width="100%">

$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtpi',
    buttons: [
        'colvis',
        'colvisRestore'
    ],
    columns: [
      null,
      {visible: false}
    ]
  });
});
```

[Testing](http://live.datatables.net/poqoyezo/5/edit) is easy - After click to button `Column visibility` try change `width` of output `div` (or your browser window) and columns are hiding or showing by width of window.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "table";
            output.Attributes.Add("id", Id);
            output.Attributes.Add("class", "table table-hover table-responsive-md");
            output.Attributes.Add("width", "100%");

            var props = GetItemProperties();
            var include = GetIncludeProperties();

            TableHeadBuilder(output, props, include);
        }
```

Use `output.Attributes.Add("width", "100%");` in the table view html. No need to use `responsive` in side the script.
The above example shows for using TagHelper.